# Help with placing an image on 3D text

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

I've been trying to add an image to some 3D Text for a while now but unfortunately, it always comes out lopsided and uneven. UV Editing doesn't seem to work with text even after it's converted into a mesh. YouTube videos aren't helping either.[image]

Here is the image I'm trying to put on the text
[image]

Here is the 3D text (selected), notice the lopsided image reflections

Thank you

Comment: Hello :). UV maps absolutely do work with text converted to mesh. You just need to properly unwrap. Perhaps *UV > Project from view* in this case.

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped the mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the text to a mesh. It's going to have a lot of tris.
Select all in edit mode and clck on 'Mesh' at the header of the 3D viewport and click on ''Clean Up'.
Select 'Limited Dissolve' which will drastically reduce the number of tris appearing while retaining form of the text mesh.
You can further increase the value of the limited Dissolve' from it's adjustment pop up bar that appears at the bottom left immediately you click on it hence reducing the mesh's noisy face Tris but do this slighty as giving an high value input will make the mesh to loose form.
At this point you should be able to use the 'Smart UV Project' which will project something quite relatable then go ahead texturing. Should work out fine now.